# Make {external-images} a synonym of {graphics}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I just realized that there's an [external-images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-images) tag with (at the moment) 16 questions. Given the definition of the [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag

> {graphics} is about inclusion of
>   graphical material in your document
>   from an external file

it seems that [external-images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-images) is redundant. It should be made a synonym of [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), and the existing questions should be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a week has passed and my proposal has gained some upvotes, I ask a moderator to implement it (i.e. making [external-images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-images) a synonym of [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), merging existing questions).

Answer (score -1):

I think that [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) should be broadened to include any method for getting graphics into a document, be it external ([graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphicx)) or programmatic ([tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [xy-pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xy-pic), or [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks)).

Comment: For "general" questions about programmatically created pictures, there's the {diagrams} tag. See the respective tag wiki entries.

Comment: The broader a tag is the less useful it is. The way the word 'graphics' is used in LaTeX commands, most notable in `\includegraphics`, it is a synonym of (raster-)images. I normally call the programmatic created {diagrams} "pictures" because thats their common part of the LaTeX environment names.

Comment: Hm.  I forgot about `diagrams`--I guess that's suitable.