# Tag synonyms and how they work

Tags: support, tagging, tag-synonyms

There are a large number of questions on meta that deal with tag synonyms, requesting a merger via so-called synonyms. To name a few:

- [Should {accepted-answer} be a synonym of {accepting}?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/5764)
- [Make {dashes} and {comma} synonyms of {punctuation}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2371/5764)
- [Make {external-images} a synonym of {graphics}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1271/5764)
- ...

However, in some dark, concealed janitorial closet, there actually exists (what seems to me) [a formal place where tag synonyms are/could be suggested, vetted, approved or declined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). My question relates to the best practice to utilize this feature. For example, what is the best (sometimes fastest) option:

- Post a question on [Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) (similar to the above); or
- Follow a process and nominate synonyms formally.

Take, for example, the following two tags on Meta: [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) and [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging). The latter exists (for whatever reason) and could be used as a tag synonym for [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) yet it has no questions tagged with it. The criteria for community approval and engagement in this process is also somewhat strict:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: Great question! It seems only tags that have at least one question can be suggested as synonyms: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yXaB7.png. Afaik, tags with no questions are automatically deleted after a certain amount of time. Overall, the tag synonym functionality doesn’t seem to be too important to the devs; it isn’t even present in the 10k tools, which would make perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having just occupied myself with a bunch of tagging activities, I have to say that this function really is hidden most obscurely.  My opinion on your question is that we should do both: propose a synonym, and then notify Meta.  It appears that the only way to actually vote on a proposed synonym is by following several links and then searching for pending proposals in a big list, so it seems quite unlikely that even the limited population of Meta users will ever find them.  The Meta post will therefore attract some attention, in addition to providing an opportunity to explain the proposal.

I'm actually going to go out and do that with mine now...

Comment: I think this is actually a great idea. To post a question on Meta as a formal request, with a guide to the voting area. Once a decision has been made, someone (including the OP) can post an answer. Although I might even be inclined to suggest such a question be closed, I don't think it falls under any of the closing categories, so a short answer should be fine. Hey, it's on meta, so why not...