# Proposed synonym: {tikzpicture} -> {tikz-pgf}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

This post is to test the proposal I gave in answer to [Tag synonyms and how they work](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3499/575).

I have proposed the tag synonym [tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikzpicture) -> [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), which you can vote on at the following page: [{tikz-pgf} synonyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-pgf/synonyms).

I found that the [tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikzpicture) tag was almost entirely unused, and those uses were probably accidents, and in any case that any question that could be tagged by it would be equally appropriate for [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) in general, since virtually all uses of the `tikz` package go through `tikzpicture`.  Note that [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz) already redirects to this tag.

Comment: Upvoted the proposal, +1!

Comment: @doncherry: Oh, is that how you do tags :)

Comment: @RyanReich: Yes, I just [posted some discussion on this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3521/5764) in Meta. I noticed this during some of your tag wiki edits/additions. Excerpts should *not* include them using markdown (since the excerpt does not support the syntax) but should include them using a verbatim {<tag>} syntax. In contrast, tag wikis should definitely use them.

Comment: @Werner: I learned what you say by (trial and) error while editing, so indeed, many of my excerpts are a little broken.

Answer (score 8):

The synonym has been approved.